# retrieve local html form

Tags: python, html, forms

I have a html page that contains a form and I would like a user to be able to input some data in the form. I would then retrieve this data with a python script.

I don't understand how to make the html and python communicate. How can the python retrieve the form after the user has clicked on post? Is there a basic example I can use to demonstrate this?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is an HTTP server. Python can be used to make a server, or you could get one such as Apache or Lighttpd. I wrote an example application (Rock, Paper, Scissors) based off of this a while ago: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95437705/RPS_Web.tgz

Comment: This link displays a 404 page not found error. Is there an updated version?

Comment: Reuploaded to Dropbox, should be fine now

Answer (score 1):

C0deH4cker is right that you should have your python program running somewhere in some kind of web server.

A proper way to do this for larger projects is to use a web framework like Django or Web2py. These frameworks have excellent documentation and tutorial pages that are well worth the effort of consuming. A smaller benefit is that both have their own built-in webserver for development an small deployment.

Another way is to write python code that has a web server of its own. You could have a look at Twisted, the networking framework for python. Good info is at http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/index.html.

Finally -- but this is considered a bit outdated, I guess (??) -- there is the CGI option you describe. Most web servers like apache and lighttpd have the option to run CGI scripts. CGI scripts are very simple programs that, in their simplest form, when run, output HTML code on their stdout. The webserver looks at the first ("shebang") line in the script to determine the script interpreter, executes the script, picks up the output and serves it over HTTP.

Specific provisions have been made in CGI for parameter passing. In the Python CGI module, these are obtainable through cgi.FieldStorage()

First for some HTML:

An HTML form has an "action" and a "method" attribute. Action is the URL (absolute, or relative to the current path) where it will send the form data to; Method is the method to use, usually for a form with a submit button this is "POST".

So if you have this HTML code running somewhere:

```
<html>
<body>
  <form name="sample" action="cgi-bin/myscript.cgi" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When the user presses the submit button, all input values are posted to the URL "myprogram.cgi".

A good text on what CGI code should look like is in http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html .

Some code that should work is:

```
import cgi

print "Content-Type: text/html"     # HTML is following
print                               # blank line, end of headers

print "<TITLE>CGI script output</TITLE>"
print "<body>\n"
print "<H1>This is my first CGI script</H1>"
print "Hello, world!"

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
if "name" not in form: 
    print "<H1>Error</H1>"
    print "Please fill in the name fields"
else:
    print "<p>name:", form["name"].value
print "</body>"
```

Now, it is important that you realize that you have to make this code available on the specified URL from a web server. How you should do this depends on your web server.

On apache under linux, you would normally put the script in /var/www/cgi-bin. Possibly you should enable cgi execution in the apache configuration, as it may be switched off for security reasons.